# How to get column names from the result of a select query using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to create a script that goes through the results from MySQL and automatically returns the column names selected on the query using mysqli.
**NOTE: I'll be using some pseudo code to explain my point easier. It is obviously wrong**

For example a `CLIENTS` table with columns:

```
ID, NAME, EMAIL, TELEPHONE, ADDRESS
```

If I have a query:

```
$result =  $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM CLIENTS WHERE ID = 1");
```

I need the script to return  ID NAME, EMAIL, TELEPHONE, ADDRESS.

**Pseudo code:**

```
foreach ($result as $column => $value){
   echo $column
}
```

Result:

`ID, NAME, EMAIL, TELEPHONE, ADDRESS,`

Same thing if the query is only

```
$result =  $mysqli->query("SELECT NAME as N, EMAIL as E FROM CLIENTS WHERE ID = 1");
```

The script should return only:

```
N, E,
```

Ideas?

Comment: Looks like your pseudo foreach  code pretty well covers it, assuming you have come across mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: The idea with SO is you try it and if it fails, then and only then do you bother asking a question

Comment: @RiggsFolly mysqli_fetch_assoc was exactly what I was looking for, please add it as an answer so I can give it to you. I don't know why so much hate for a legit question. Thanks!!!

Comment: Someone already did, so go with there answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a complete working snippet, but instead a nod in the right direction.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id = 1";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
$colNames = array_keys($row);
```

Now `$row` contains an associative array with all column names and variables for the first selected row. If you only want the column names, you have them in `$colNames` and you're done.

To process all the data use

```
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also query to database with this query in PHP:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```